# You have already activated rack 1.3.2, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.2.3. Consider using bundle exec

Tags: ruby, passenger, rack

I've got a problem while i try to run my app :

```
You have already activated rack 1.3.2, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.2.3. Consider using bundle exec.
```

I read a lot about this kind of error, but i did not find any solution that worked for me

- I already removed my Gemfile.lock and re-run bundle as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060749/deactivate-a-gem-you-have-already-activated-rake-0-9-3-beta-1-but-my-gemfile)
- I already use the latest version of passenger (3.0.8) - as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060749/deactivate-a-gem-you-have-already-activated-rake-0-9-3-beta-1-but-my-gemfile)
- The `bundle exec rake` trick cannot be used in my case

Thank you per advance

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you can't use `bundle exec rake` in your case?

Comment: Simply because the error stack shows that the error raised in ´gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb´, and i'd rather not play with this kind of files

Comment: `Bundle exec` is totally safe and as far as I know it's the recommended way of calling rake and other scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but i don't really know where in my rails app i have to configure the use of `bundle exec rake`

Comment: You don't have to configure anything, just prefix the commands in the console.

Did you try to `bundle update` this gets the latest versions and overwrites Gemfile.lock.

Comment: Has anyone solved this issue yet? I'm getting this same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Run `bundle install --binstubs` and you'll get **bin** directory in your application root with all executables needed by app.

Then you need to add this dir to path and best place to do it - .rvmrc if you use RVM.

```
[ -d './bin' ] && export PATH=`pwd`/bin:$PATH
```

or just run ./bin/{rake|rails|etc} from your app root.

Answer (score 3):

Try prefixing the command to run your server with bundle exec, i.e.

```
bundle exec rails server
```

Or in production (if you're using something like Unicorn

```
bundle exec unicorn [options]
```