# RubyGems rack version update issue

Tags: rubygems, rack

I have a problem with my Serve set up. I ran an update of my gem files and now when I boot serve (or Sinatra) I get this error:

```
/Users/yannick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53: warning: already initialized constant WFKV_
/Users/yannick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup': You have already activated rack 1.3.4, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.3.3. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
```

I've seen a few solutions around the web and here on Stackoverflow, they all recommend to running bundle update, specify the rack version in the gem file, delete the gemfile.lock or run bundle exec.

I've tried all of them but to no avail.

As for the bundle exec command is there a difference between rack and rake. If i run bunde exec rake like in there:

[You have already activated rack 1.3.2, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.2.3. Consider using bundle exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243624/you-have-already-activated-rack-1-3-2-but-your-gemfile-requires-rack-1-2-3-cons)

I just get a message saying that there is no rake service running.

```
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
```

If I try to do a bundle exec rack, I get a no such exec message.

```
bundler: command not found: rack
```

I've re-run bundle install / update a few time and each time that i try to boot my serve project it fails to start with the same error.

On the other hand, if I require the latest rack 1.3.4 and start a new project, i get the error but the serve server works. If i run the serve server on my existing project, the server boot but can't find the pages. it says something like:

```
/path/to/my/views/file.slim/path/to/my/views/file.slim
```

the path to the correct file in my view folder get repeated twice and therefore doesn't load...

Comment: Strange things happen.

I gave up on the rack 1.3.4 v 1.3.3 issue
I duplicated my folder to try to remove things and fix the mess, but to be sure i just ran the Serve server in the exact copy and it work just fine.

Mistery ...

The issue for the rack error message is documented here:
https://github.com/jlong/serve/issues/53